# Resta entre dos campos SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

hola buenos dias tengo el siguiente problema
necesito obtener la diferencia entre dos campos. Dichos campos tengo que sumar el total de todos sus valores y luego hacer la restar PERO ME TIRA CUALQUIER RESULTADO UNA VEZ HECHA LA RESTA

DESDE YA AGRADEZCO SUS RESPUESTAS

```
SELECT SUM(ovd.precio_unitario_final) - SUM(pd.suma_pago)  AS 
diferencia
FROM pagos p
INNER JOIN orden_venta as ov on p.id_ov = ov.id_ov
INNER JOIN pagos_detalle as pd on p.id_pago = pd.id_pago
INNER JOIN orden_venta_detalle as ovd on ov.id_ov = ovd.id_ov
GROUP BY ovd.precio_unitario_final , pd.suma_pago
```

Comment: Si eliminas el `group by` te devolverá un solo resultado.

Comment: Por favor define mejor que significa "CUALQUIER RESULTADO".

Comment: select SUM(pd.suma_pago)
from pagos_detalle as pd = 3529 -----------------------   select SUM(ov.precio_unitario_final)
from orden_venta_detalle as ov = 6630

Comment: los valores del resulta de la funcion = 46.18
400.77  
  1418.36
  -4895.00
  -7011.00
  -8464.00

Comment: Entiende que algunos números sin tener idea de los datos ni de lo que estás queriendo hacer o al menos lo que esperas, no nos ayuda mucho a ayudarte. Lo único que te puedo decir es que es inconsistente que sumes por columnas que intervienen en un group by, justamente las funciones de agregación se aplican sobre columnas que no se agrupan. Quita el group by como ya te mencionó rencinas y revisa si ese es el resultado que estás esperando

Answer (score 0):

Estimado una forma de hacerlo es de esta manera, ahora es importante que aunque paresca obvio te cerciores de que el tipo de datos de las columna es de tipo int o double

```
select SUM(ovd.precio_unitario_final) as 'preciofinal',SUM(pd.suma_pago) as 'sumapago',
preciofinal - sumapago as diferencia 
from pagos p inner join orden_venta as ov on p.id_ov = ov.id_ov inner join 
pagos_detalle as pd on p.id_pago = pd.id_pago inner join orden_venta_detalle as ovd on 
ov.id_ov = ovd.id_ov group by ovd.precio_unitario_final , pd.suma_pago
```

Comment: preciofinal - sumapago as diferencia .... no me toma esas columnas no se por que (nombre de columnas invalidas)... si los tipo de datos con los mismo (decimal)

Comment: Es muy probable que no te este tomando el alias de las tablas del inner join "INNER JOIN pagos_detalle as pd"   por el echo de poner "as" eso no es necesario debe ser de esta manera "INNER JOIN pagos_detalle pd"

Comment: Los nombres 'preciofinal' y 'sumapago' son resueltos por el motor al final de todo el resto de las operaciones, por consiguiente no pueden usarse en un calculo como lo estás haciendo, a menos claro que uses una subconsulta

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (SUM(ovd.precio_unitario_final) - SUM(pd.suma_pago))  
AS 
diferencia
FROM pagos p
INNER JOIN orden_venta as ov on p.id_ov = ov.id_ov
INNER JOIN pagos_detalle as pd on p.id_pago = pd.id_pago
INNER JOIN orden_venta_detalle as ovd on ov.id_ov = 
ovd.id_ov
GROUP BY ovd.precio_unitario_final , pd.suma_pago
```

Comment: igmer gracias! pero me sigue tirando cualquier resultado

Answer (score 0):

Si realmente necesitas la diferencia de la suma de TODOS los valores de ambos campos, entonces haz las sumas por separado y luego restas.

```
SELECT
    (SELECT SUM(precio_unitario_final) FROM orden_venta_detalle) -
    (SELECT SUM(suma_pago) FROM pagos_detalle)
AS diferencia;
```

Dudo que esto sea relamente lo que necesitas, pero así es como lo has expresado.